# CRM 2011 javascript debugger not working after rollup update

Tags: javascript, debugging, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I Install upadate rollup 2 yesterday. After update I can not see correct break point, and so i can not debug my javascript codes. When i try to debug my javascript code, visual studio 2010 is opening on new session, but the breakpoint is somewhere else, not on my code point. It was wokring until update the CRM.

Edit: The problem appear on ribbon command. When try to call a javascript function from ribbon button, its not debbugging. It was working before.

How can i resolve this?
any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Several developers that I work with have experienced this same problem. Usually if you let the function be called once (however you're expecting it to be invoked) then reload the script on to the form containing the function, you can hit a debugger statement if you invoke the function yet again (for enable/disable rules this can be accomplished by using the IE dev toolbar and calling into the form to reevaluate the ribbon).

Reevaluating the ribbon rules can be done by calling the following from the dev toolbar:

```
frames[0].Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon();
```

A bookmarklet I created to reload the script on the form (you enter the path to the script ie if the resource is at http://crm/orgname/WebResource/org_Script.js you'd enter org_Script.js at the prompt):

```
javascript:(function(){var path=prompt("Namespaced Path to File:","");var s=document.frames[0].document.createElement("script");s.src=prependOrgName("/WebResources/"+path);document.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})();
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if I can explain further.

Comment: Thanks for answer and sorry for late feedback. I couldnt understand what i have to do. I try to run frames[0].Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon(); but response is undefined. Can you please explain what i have to do, step by step.. Thanks..